# How to get rid of code repetition here (lint errors)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Here's my code, and I would like to get rid of this because it's causing me lint errors, 
but I don't have idea how to refactor this to get this somehow cleaner etc..

```
formatter: value => {
      switch (value) {
        case PRODUCT_STATUS.Sold:
          return (
            <span className="product">
              PRODUCT
            </span>
          );
        case PRODUCT_STATUS.OnStock:
          return (
            <span className="product success">
              ON STOCK
            </span>
          );
        case PRODUCT_STATUS.Expired:
          return (
            <span className="product error">
              EXPIRED
            </span>
          );
        default:
          return 'STATUS DEFAULT';
      }
}
```

Thanks guys

Cheers

Comment: What are the lint errors?

Comment: If you don't wanna solve the errors but improve the code I think this question would fit better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a function to generate the template and call that in each case, then I think the linter will be happy:

```
function template(cssClasses, text) {
   return `
     <span class="${cssClasses}">
       ${text}
     </span>
  `;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const config = {
  [PRODUCT_STATUS.Sold]: {text: 'PRODUCT', className: 'product'},
  [PRODUCT_STATUS.OnStock]: {text: 'ON STOCK', className: 'product success'}  ,   
  [PRODUCT_STATUS.Expired]: {text: 'EXPIRED', className: 'product errorr'}
}


formatter: value => {
  const details = config[value]
  return details ? <span className={details.className}>{details.text}</span>
        : 'STATUS DEFAULT'
}
```

it's even faster than switch https://jsperf.com/if-switch-lookup-table/10

Answer (score 0):

Like below. Its the same as Sam H. already posted, but since i wrote it too here goes:

```
function render(css, status) {

 return (
      <span className={"product "+ css}>
      {status}
    </span>
  );
}

function formatter(value) {
    let result = null;
    switch (value) {
    case PRODUCT_STATUS.Sold:
      return render("sold", "SOLD");
    case PRODUCT_STATUS.OnStock:
      return render("sold", "ON STOCK");
    default:
      return render("", "DEFAULT");
  }
}
```

Also i wondered if the default should be non-element? In this example it'll also be wrapped in span.